# How to create a scratch pad in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

This is a very simple question. I often find myself wanting to create a scratch pad/buffer in Eclipse in which I need to copy-paste something or write some notes without creating a file for it.

For example, when I am working in Vim, I can create a new buffer with `:new` (actually a shortcut key mapped to `:new`) and get going. Or in most other editors, I can just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to create a new buffer.

Is this possible in Eclipse?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Maybe this could do:
"File" -> "New" -> "Other" -> "General" -> "Untitled text file"

Comment: Works great! It's also present in the File Menu -> New -> Untitled text file, and I was able to assign a keyboard shortcut to it as well.

Comment: It is also listed in in 'Quick Access' - `CTRL+3`.

Comment: Pro: In contrast to the option 'General - > File', this does not require a storage location. Con: The content is not persisted like, e.g. in the 'Commit Message' area of the 'Git Staging' view.

Comment: How do you set the file type / chose the editor?

Comment: somewhat useful if you're looking specifically for a java scratch file 
https://nzpcmad.blogspot.com/2005/11/eclipse-writing-java-snippets-in.html